# HtmlUnit, can't be redirected to other site

Tags: java, htmlunit

I want to log in on [csgolounge](http://csgolounge.com) using my SteamAccount. I'm using HtmlUnit.

What I have done:
1. Click on [csgolounge](http://csgolounge.com) on login by the SteamAccount.
2. Fill username and password on steamcommunity.com and click submit button
3. Fill token code from steam mobile app (manually) and click on log in button
Now I should be redirected to csgolounge where I should be logged on. But I'm still on steamcommunity site, and can't be redirected. There is my code:

```
public class Logger {

    public void logIn(String username, String password) {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
        try {
            // login to csgolounge.com using SteamAccount
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(Constants.CSGOLOUNGE_URL);
            HtmlAnchor loginAnchor = (HtmlAnchor) page.getByXPath("//div[@id='status']/a[2]").get(0);
            HtmlPage pageAfterClick = loginAnchor.click();  
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000L);
            HtmlAnchor steamLoginAnchor = (HtmlAnchor) pageAfterClick.getByXPath("//div[@id='logIn']/form[1]/div[1]/div[last()]/a[1]").get(0);
            HtmlPage steamLoginPage = steamLoginAnchor.click();
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000L);
            // login on steamcomminity.com
            HtmlTextInput usernameInput = (HtmlTextInput) steamLoginPage.getElementById("steamAccountName");            
            HtmlPasswordInput passwordInput = (HtmlPasswordInput) steamLoginPage.getElementById("steamPassword");
            HtmlSubmitInput loginButton = (HtmlSubmitInput) steamLoginPage.getElementById("imageLogin");            
            usernameInput.setValueAttribute(username);
            passwordInput.setValueAttribute(password);
            HtmlPage steamPageAfterClickLogIn = loginButton.click();
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000L);
            // I need to write token code from steam mobile app
            HtmlTextInput codeAfterLoginInput = (HtmlTextInput) steamPageAfterClickLogIn.getElementById("twofactorcode_entry");
            HtmlDivision codeSubmitDiv = (HtmlDivision) steamPageAfterClickLogIn.getByXPath("//div[@id='login_twofactorauth_buttonset_entercode']/div[1]").get(0);
            codeAfterLoginInput.setValueAttribute(getLoginCode());
            // and there I should be redirected to csgolounge, where I should be logged on
            HtmlPage pageAfterSendingCode = codeSubmitDiv.click();
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000L);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    private String getLoginCode() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please write ur code:");
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = new Logger();
        logger.logIn(Constants.USERNAME, Constants.PASSWORD);
    }

}
```

Where I made a mistake?

EDIT1:
Maybe there is a problem with onclick action, because there is no onclick() on codeSubmitDiv, but when I click on it using web browser, it works somehow. Check the screen imgur.com/a/QYp56

Comment: Enable HttpClient wire log and check if the stuff send over the wire is the same your browser sends. And check clicking the submitDiv will really trigger the expected behavior.

Comment: [Logs](http://pastebin.com/2ZXxUcMq) didn't give me too much. I don't really know how to check if clicking of the codeSubmitDiv behave as I expected.